# C++ Vector Iterator: Compare and Erase Two Elements

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

I have a `std::vector<Shape*>` called scene which stores pointers to Shapes. I need to be able to iterate through the vector, comparing the shape pointed to by the iterator with the next shape in the iterator. If the return of `s1->intersects(*s2)` is true, I need to remove both s1 and s2 from the vector. The following code isn't correct, I get an exception `vector interator is not incrementable`.

How can I solve this problem?

```
while (scene.size() > 1)
{
    for (std::vector<Shape*>::iterator it = scene.begin(); it != scene.end() - 1; it++)
    {
        Shape* s1 = (*it);
        Shape* s2 = (*(it + 1));

        if (s1->intersects(*s2))
        {
            delete s1;
            delete s2;

            // Remove the pointers to s1 and s2 from the vector.
            it = scene.erase(it);
            it = scene.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as how your code already assumes there are no null pointers in the vector, you can use a null pointer as a marker for deletion, simplifying the logic greatly by separating the marking from the erasing.

```
for (std::vector<Shape*>::iterator it = scene.begin(); it < scene.end() - 1; ++it)
{
    Shape*& s1 = (*it);
    Shape*& s2 = (*(it + 1));
    if (s1->intersects(*s2))
    {
        delete s1;
        delete s2;
        s1 = NULL;
        s2 = NULL;
        ++it;
    }
}

scene.erase(std::remove(scene.begin(), scene.end(), NULL), scene.end());
```

As an aside, your original code could have probably been fixed by changing `it != scene.end() - 1` to `it < scene.end() - 1`.  Because if you end up erasing the last two elements, you'll have an iterator which is equal to `scene.end()`, which satisfies the condition `it != scene.end() - 1`, and the loop will try to increment it.

Comment: That's almost right (and nice!), but as the intersection case sets `s2` to `NULL` then increments `it` by only one position, `s1->` will be a `NULL` pointer dereference on the next loop.

Comment: Looking good, +1 and curtains for my answer - this has less element copying.

Answer (score 0):

vector iterator becomes invalid when it is erased.
you should use vector::erase (iterator first, iterator last); to erase multiple objects in the vector at the same time.